# Can't download excel file from C#

Tags: c#, excel, model-view-controller

I'm working on adding Export functionality to an existing site. I've created an Excel file, and I'm able to output it to my local directory, but when I try pushing the file to the user using Response, nothing happens. I've viewed several differnet articles and Stack questions, and none seem to be different from what I have, or work when I apply them.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
public void Export () {
     //Create instance of the database
     ExportContext eDB = new ExportContext();

     var query = (from x in eDB.EMPLOYEES
                      select x);

     IEnumerable<EMPLOYEES> employees = query.ToList();

     //Set filename to Table + date/time
     string fileName = "EMPLOYEES" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ".xlsx";

     //Create excel package
     ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
     var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employees");
     worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(employees, true);

     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        //Output the file to the user via download
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
     }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a different `ContentType application/vnd.ms-excel` ? Also, do you see any type of errors in the console (F12)?

Comment: Can you share any error or warning message?

Comment: There are no errors or warnings, stepping through the code executes the whole thing.

Comment: As well as what AussieJoe wrote, the short date format might be a problem. I suggest using `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` so that there is no chance of having characters which make it go wrong.

Comment: And I haven't tried a differnt ContentType yet, as the excel file type is from a Nuget package I'm unfamiliar with and I'm following an example found here (Approach 4): https://techbrij.com/export-excel-xls-xlsx-asp-net-npoi-epplus

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've updated the string (`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm")` time may be necessary in case they download multiple times a day). Still nothing.

Comment: @MitchBoutilier 1) I think that AuusieJoe intended for you to use the developer tools in the browser (press F12 to open them) and then look at the network tab to see if there are any indications as to what has gone wrong. 2) I suggest removing the `Response.End()`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Removed the `Response.End()`, still no file. I also don't see any error or warnings in the Dev console.

Comment: @MitchBoutilier OK, try saving the file to the file system and using [Response.TransmitFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile?view=netframework-4.7.2). Oh, and you are doing this in an ashx handler, not an aspx page, aren't you?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's actually within an MVC controller (C# class). I actually have to run (end of day and I have a wedding rehearsal to get to) but I'll keep plugging away at this over the weekend when I can. I apologize for leaving before we could get this resolved, and thanks for your help! I'll try the file system/Response.TransmitFile() method first thing Monday.

Comment: show the code that works for the local directory output too. That would help.